# How can echo a json data after an email sent in codeigniter

Tags: android, json, codeigniter, email

I am using codeigniter email, to send an email to the client who has registerd him self into the system, and after that I echo a json code that syas an email has been sent to you.
this proccess is working when i am using web browser, but it is not working in android application.
my code is below:

```
$config = Array(
     'protocol' => 'smtp',
     'smtp_host' => 'smtp.1and1.com',
     'smtp_port' => 587,
     'smtp_user' => $from_email, 
     'smtp_pass' => $this->config->item('email_password'), 
     'mailtype' => 'html',
     'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
     'wordwrap' => TRUE
                      ); 

$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->from($from_email, "something");
$this->email->reply_to($from_email, "something");
$this->email->to($to_email);
$this->email->subject("Account Verification");   
$this->email->set_mailtype("html"); 
$this->email->message($email_body);
if($this->email->send()){
        $rsp['error'] = 0;
        $rsp['data']  = $user;
        echo json_encode($rsp);}else{do some thing...}
```

but if i remove the `$this->email->send()` from code, then the echo json code works fine, but not emil sendig.

Comment: can any one help me to suggest a solution?

Comment: How did you call from android? please show me the android part

Answer (score 0):

```
$config = Array(
     'protocol' => 'smtp',
     'smtp_host' => 'smtp.1and1.com',
     'smtp_port' => 587,
     'smtp_user' => $from_email, 
     'smtp_pass' => $this->config->item('email_password'), 
     'mailtype' => 'html',
     'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
     'wordwrap' => TRUE
                      ); 

      $this->load->library('email', $config);
      $this->email->from($from_email, "something");
      $this->email->reply_to($from_email, "something");
      $this->email->to($to_email);
      $this->email->subject("Account Verification");   
      $this->email->set_mailtype("html"); 
      $this->email->message($email_body);
      $this->email->send();
        $rsp['error'] = 0;
        $rsp['data']  = $user;
        echo json_encode($rsp);
```

like this try once

Comment: I already tried that, but still is not working, the problem is with line '$this->email->send();'. if i remove this the json part works

Comment: **$rsp['error'] = 0;
        $rsp['data']  = $user;
        echo json_encode($rsp);** write model and call  that model

Comment: i thing this way is not working, can you help me to provide another solution like using cron job or ...

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
if ($this->email->send()) {
    echo json_encode($rsp);
} else {
    // do some thing...
}
```

means that JSON will be printed only if **send()** function return true. If it returns false, then the logic will go to else section and no JSON will be printed (unless you modify **// do some thing** to print JSON also).

I'm pretty sure that mail() return false. You are using CI, don't forget to check **application/logs/*.log** to see the error detail.

Comment: I also have put it in the else part 'echo json_encode($rsp);' but still is not working

Comment: When you put echo json_encode(...) in both 'if' and 'else', you must receive one of them. That's the logic. But, if you receive nothing, it seems that your script terminates during executing send() function. Could you find any usable information in the logs file?